# Convert MySQL join to JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have a table named `calls` and a table named `uploads` that are structured as follows:

**Calls**

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ call_id ║ caller_id ║ call_time           ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 235     ║ 23        ║ 2017-11-01 12:47:27 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 259     ║ 65        ║ 2017-11-02 16:58:27 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

**Uploads**

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ upload_id ║ call_id ║ file_name           ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 145       ║ 235     ║ bu2t7384uhjnfns.mp3 ║
╠═══════════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ 146       ║ 235     ║ jbwer8y23gr92o.mp3  ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

I then have a query which joins the two tables:

```
SELECT calls.*, uploads.*
FROM cads
LEFT OUTER JOIN uploads ON uploads.call_id = 235
```

When I use `return $query->result_array()` in codeigniter and then `json_encode` it returns an array with two `call` elements:

```
calls:(2) [{…}, {…}]
```

I would like to have only one `call` element in my JSON object, but have a key named `uploads` which is an array of uploads from the uploads table, e.g. something like this:

```
calls: Array(1)
  0:
    call_id: 235
    caller_id: 23
    call_time: 2017-11-01 12:47:27
    uploads: Array(2)
       0: 
         upload_id: 145
         call_id: 235
         file_name: bu2t7384uhjnfns.mp3
       1:
         upload_id: 146
         call_id: 235
         file_name: jbwer8y23gr92o.mp3
```

Bonus points for anyone who can show me how to display the above JSON in Handlebars-JS :)

Comment: Whats in `calls:(2) [{…}, {…}]`? (show preferably in an array or json format). Are you happy with the result or do you want us to rewrite that too? What have you tried? Whats Handlebars goto do with it, json is json..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$results` is the return from the database and looks like this

```
array (size=2)
  0 => array (size=5)
      'call_id' => string '235' (length=3)
      'caller_id' => string '23' (length=2)
      'call_time' => string '2017-11-01 12:47:27' (length=19)
      'upload_id' => string '145' (length=3)
      'file_name' => string 'bu2t7384uhjnfns.mp3' (length=19)
  1 => array (size=5)
      'call_id' => string '235' (length=3)
      'caller_id' => string '23' (length=2)
      'call_time' => string '2017-11-01 12:47:27' (length=19)
      'upload_id' => string '146' (length=3)
      'file_name' => string 'jbwer8y23gr92o.mp3 ' (length=19)
```

Here is one way to reformat the two database rows as you ask.

```
$calls = $results[0];
//remove unwanted indexes
unset($calls['upload_id'], $calls['upload_id'], $calls['file_name']);
//gather the upload sub-arrays
foreach($results as $result)
{
     //remove unwanted indexes
     unset($result['caller_id'], $result['call_time']);
     //add sub-array to "upload" 
     $calls['upload'][] = $result;
}
$data = array($calls); //put it all into an array
$encode = json_encode($data);
var_dump($encode);
```

The `var_dump($encode)` produces

```
[[{"call_id":"235","caller_id":"23","call_time":"2017-11-01 12:47:27","upload":[{"call_id":"235","upload_id":"145","file_name":"bu2t7384uhjnfns.mp3"},{"call_id":"235","upload_id":"146","file_name":"jbwer8y23gr92o.mp3 "}]}]]' (length=223)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your returning data in $result.

```
$result = array(

  array(
    'call_id'   => 235,
    'caller_id' => 23,
    'call_time' => '2017-11-01 12:47:27',
    'upload_id' => 145,
    'file_name' => 'bu2t7384uhjnfns.mp3'
    ),
  array(
    'call_id'   => 235,
    'caller_id' => 23,
    'call_time' => '2017-11-01 12:47:27',
    'upload_id' => 146,
    'file_name' => 'jbwer8y23gr92o.mp3'
   )
 );

 //    echo '<pre>';
 //    print_r($result);
```

This builds the json result. (I'm probably missing a clever existing php function that automagically does this without all the arrays, etc.)

```
 $call_uploads = array();
 $calls = array();
 $uploads = array();

 foreach($result as $ups) {

   if (empty($call)) {
     $call = array(
       'call_id'   => $ups['call_id'],
       'caller_id' => $ups['caller_id'],
       'call_time' => $ups['call_time']
     );
   }

   $upload = array(
     'upload_id' => $ups['upload_id'],
     'call_id'   => $ups['call_id'],
     'file_name' => $ups['file_name']
   );

   array_push($uploads, $upload);

 };

 $call['uploads'] = $uploads;

 array_push($calls, $call);
 $call_uploads['calls'] = $calls;

 //print_r($call_uploads);

 $j = json_encode($call_uploads);

 //print_r($j);
```

Sorry, don't know Handlebars.